# ajax google forms blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-forms

I try to send data to google forms, by using google form input names with ajax.
But getting cors error.

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/FORM-ID/formResponse',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    statusCode: {
        0: function() {
            console.log('Enter on error');
            swal({
                title: "Error!",
                text: "error",
                type: "error",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok"
            });
        },
        200: function() {
            console.log('Enter on success');
            swal({
                title: "Success",
                text: "Your information submitted successfully!",
                type: "success",
                confirmButtonText: "Ok"
            });
        }
    }

});
```

My Headers:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, post, get');
header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
?>
```

Errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/FORM-ID/formResponse' from
> origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST
> https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/FORM-ID/formResponse
> net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: And whats the question? They are not allowing this. Are you asking how to bypass security?

Comment: It is not YOU who set those headers. It is the TARGET that needs to set those headers. Your client needs to be allowed by THEM. For example on PHP your server needs to be an actual domain and not localhost

Comment: @IncredibleHat I have that cors error.

Comment: @mplungjan So if I test on Domain, it should work fine?

Comment: If you upload to `https://yourdomain.com/yourfile.php`AND they allow `yourdomain.com`, then yes

Comment: still same issue in domain. Maybe problem is with post method to google forms? @mplungjan

Comment: [have a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22docs.google.com/forms%22+api+cors+site:stackoverflow.com)